# Skype prevents login because it believes another instance of Skype is already running

Tags: 10.10, skype

Skype 2.1 has been working in Ubuntu 10.10 but now stops me from logging in - it says **there maybe another instance of Skype running**. **There is not, so I can't use Skype**. I have changed passwords several times but this hasn't rectified the problem. Please can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Skype may be running. It is an issue which I haven't solved yet and I am using Skype (Beta) Version 2.1.0.81, I am yet waiting for the release of the new version which seems to be going to correct this and other bugs.

Meanwhile, what you can do when facing this is to kill all the running processes named "skype".

Do this by dropping: `killall skype` in a terminal or by opening your system monitor (System/Administration/System Monitor) and locate the currently running skype process, right click on it and kill it. Ending the process by using the "End Process" won't result in what you wish.

NOTE: If `killall skype` in a terminal don't kill the process you will be in the need to do the System Monitor trick.

[image]

After that, try again running a new instance of skype and log in.

Good luck!

Comment: I enjoy the more concise `pkill skype`. If skype continued to exist, I would upgrade to first degree murder: `pkill -9 skype`. The former politely asks skype to get its affairs in order and commit hari-kari, the latter doesn't care and ends skype instantly with potential for data loss.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Skype was not running (even though it thought it was). The solution was to close Skype and then `rm ~/.Skype`.

Comment: This solution [worked for me as well](http://askubuntu.com/a/64603/18612). Unfortunately, the OP no longer seems to exist so they can't confirm whether it solved their problem.